# Updating ubuntu requires changing the download server

Tags: apt, 14.10

So my Ubuntu 14.10 that I have installed on a laptop recently started to behave strangely.

It fails to find any new updates while I see that my desktop Ubuntu 14.10 does get new updates about twice a week atleast.

I can fix the problem by changing the server from which I want to download my updated but that only works for one update. After that I have to do it again to see new updates.

What could have gone wrong here that such behaviour exists in my machine?

My sources.list:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic main restricted
deb-src http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic universe
deb-src http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic universe
deb http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-updates universe
deb-src http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic multiverse
deb-src http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic multiverse
deb http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-security main restricted
deb-src http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-security main restricted
deb http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-security universe
deb-src http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-security universe
deb http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-security multiverse
deb-src http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ utopic-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the /etc/apt/sources.list file? Maybe you have to correct the source list.

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong there. I also edited my post with my sources. Maybe you can spot an error?